# Whitespace between buttons with AngularJS Bootstrap module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to make multiple buttons to look like menu in following code

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
      <button id="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
        Inline Dropdown
      </button>
      <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
        <li role=""><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role=""><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
      <button id="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
        Inline Dropdown
      </button>
      <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
        <li role=""><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role=""><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Everything is working fine but there is small whitespace between two divs.How can i resolve the same.

The plunker for the same is here :
https://plnkr.co/edit/W8d74Qpqm4p4oLJnNXgT?p=preview

Comment: The .btn-group and/or .dropdown class needs to be floated.  If you float left on the class the space between the two disappears.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use a navbar element instead o several dropdowns.  If you want to remove the whitespace try this:

```
.btn-group {
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the second div use inline styling or edit the original class:

```
style="margin-left:-4px"
```

OR

```
.btn-group {
display:block;
}
```